# Async function is not working when pass on as props

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have Listval function in parent component "Navbar", that i like to pass on as props to child component "Menu" as Listvalll. But it does not work.

I intend to bring it as props for on click in Modal of the Menu component. The function works ok when it is run within Menu, but is not working when i pasted it in the parent component.  Please see the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shape-omjsc

Comment: You cannot [await setState](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shape-omjsc?file=/src/components/Navbar.jsx:1083-1235) and [ll7.push(ll3);](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shape-omjsc?file=/src/components/Navbar.jsx:991-1053) is mutating state.

Comment: can you please explain more, I am new in programming. please noe=te that it works jut fine when  in child component-Menu

Comment: [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates, you could try `et ll7 = [...(this.state.Total_Item || [])];`and log `this.state.Total_Item` in render

Comment: @HMR, I tried this logic, but it is appending new objects, and the update logic is not working. thanks