# Array containing objects is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new in programming. I am trying to update cart items. On instance of click "OK" in modal, the One_item object is updated. Then this object is passed on to Cart_Item array, which contains the total items.

I tried to write the logic in Listval() function in the Menu component. The One_Item is updated properly.
But the if condition at the bottom of the Listval(), is adding , but not updating. Also the first click gives an empty object.

Please see the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-stallman-98o58

Relevant function to look into:

```
  Listval() {
    let ll = "$" + this.state.listvalue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    let ll2 = this.state.listvalue.replace(/\d+/g, "");
    let ll3 = ll2.replace(/\$/g, "");

    let ll4 = ll.replace(/\$/g, "");
    let ll5 = this.state.Select_Quantity;
    let ll6 = parseFloat(ll4) * ll5;

    let ll7 = this.state.Total_Item || [];
    ll7.push(ll3);
    ll7 = [...new Set(ll7)];

    
    this.setState(
      {
        Select_Price: ll,
        Select_Item: ll3,
        Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6,
        Total_Item: ll7
      },
      () => {
        // CHANGE: Use callback function to send data to the parent component
        this.props.updateTotalItems(this.state.Total_Item.length);
      }
    );

   
    // append  new object This is where problem starts, the new object pushes at second click

    

    if (this.state.Item !== this.state.Select_Item) {
      let xx = {
        Price: ll,
        Item: ll3,
        Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
        Total_Item_Price: ll6
      };

      // const Cart_Item = Object.assign(xx, this.state.Cart_Item);
      let yy = this.state.Cart_Item || [];
      yy.push(xx);
      this.setState({ Cart_Item: yy });
    }

    //else try to update object based on property value
   // This is not working at all. it keeps on adding objects instead of updating
    else {
      for (var i in this.state.Cart_Item) {
        if (this.state.Cart_Item[i].value === this.state.Select_Item) {
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Price = ll;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Item = ll3;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Quantity = this.state.Select_Quantity;
          this.state.Cart_Item[i].Total_Item_Price = ll6;
          // }

          break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
        }
      }

// i tried below logic as well but it didnt work
      //  this.setState({

      //   Cart_Item:this.state.Cart_Item.filter(v => v.this.state.Select_Item.includes(this.state.Item))
      //   .concat([ xx ])

      //  });
    }
    console.log(this.state.Cart_Item);
  }
```

Comment: Posting a link to the full code is rather unattractive to review and analyse. Could you please include the relevant code, the lines where the array is manipulated for example.

Comment: Thanks Tom. i have tried to paste the function with the problem

Comment: @salabb What's the point in answering your questions when you keep ignoring [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62584816/1641941). You can't push to state because it mutates.